# Error with schemaVersion of Azure Project

Tags: c#, azure

I have an Azure project in TFS that used to work well.

I've just get the latest version and rebuilt the project and now I get the following version:

```
Error   131 The XML specification is not valid: The 'schemaVersion' attribute is invalid - The value '2013-10.2.2' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition:SchemaVersion' - The Enumeration constraint failed.  D:\TFS_BOIRA\PROPPOSV3\BACKEND\ServiceLayer.Azure1\ServiceDefinition.csdef  2   125 ServiceLayer.Azure1
```

The same configuration in another computer works well.

I have checked the version of Azure Tools of both computers and we have different versions.
In my computer (Where I get the error) I have azure tools 2.3, whereas in the other computer where it works well the version is 2.2.

May it be a problem of azure tools versions?

When I add the role to the Azure cloud project, the assemblies:
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime

are updated to version 2.3.0.0, and I need them in version 2.2.0.0.

Do I have to reinstall my azure tools to the version 2.2?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep this in sync if you are working on two different machines.  Either bring both up to 2.3 or revert.  Keep in mind that as part of upgrading it may have changed config files which you haven't checked in yet.

Comment: I have unistalled the azure tools 2.3 on my computer and reopened the project. When I open it, it asks me to upgade to version 2.3, or convert the project to v2.2. The problem is that I have the second option blocked. Do you know how can I revert it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Ingrid's answer, you need to get the latest schema version within the ServiceDefinition (.csdef) and ServiceConfiguration (.cscfg) files, and it is not good enough to just change the raw version value (e.g. 2.3), you also need the new version date:

> 2.3: schemaVersion="2014-01.2.3"
>
> 2.4: schemaVersion="2014-06.2.4"

```
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="MyCoolCloudProjectName" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="4" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2014-06.2.4">

<ServiceDefinition name="MyCoolCloudProjectName" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2014-06.2.4">
```

Comment: how? keep this in sync. in my <myapp>.web.azure the toolkit verison is 2.4 and also reflected the same in the <ServiceConfiguration serviceName="<myapp>.Web.Azure" xmlns=... osFamily="4" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2014-06.2.4">   but in the web.config it is <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics... Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name...>   ,that i guess should be 2.4.0.0, but all my referenced dll of microsoft.windowsazure.* are 2.3.0.0 . Am I missing some step to synchronize. If I am correct the nuget will not update it.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. My guess is though: 1) right, it does not appear nuget updates will just update these values for you unfortunately, and 2) *my guess* is ... you probably want the schemaVersion values to match to the most recent value. But again, I don't understand the details you posted well enough.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas for reply, I resolved the issue, by installing the latest version of Azure SDK (2.5) and then re-build the solution after clean. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Finally what it worked for me was reverting the version of Azure Tools, as @Steve Newton has said.

How to revert the version it tis explained here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8701b03a-804f-4953-9ea0-01064aa4dc16/downgrade-from-18-tools-to-17?forum=azuretfs.

What I did was:

1.Modify the .ccproj file: the following two tags changing 2.3 to 2.2.

```
< ProductVersion>2.2< /ProductVersion>

< CloudExtensionsDir Condition=" '$(CloudExtensionsDir)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Windows Azure Tools\2.2\< /CloudExtensionsDir>
```

2.Open the files ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg and ServiceDefinition.csdef and change the version there.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same kind of error

[my config: java/eclipse or jenkins/azure eclipseplugin/azure sdk]

```
ServiceDefinition.csdef (2, 128): Error  CloudServices051 : The XML specification is not valid: The 'schemaVersion' attribute is invalid - The value '2014-06.2.4' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition:SchemaVersion' - The Enumeration constraint failed.
```

I had no error on my workstation using Eclipse or console but I got this error on my Jenkins instance. It was maybe a difference between SDK. I updated both ( jenkins and my workstation) with the same SDK version but I keep this error... :(

The only workaround I found to have a success build was to remove this attribute from `ServiceDefinition.csdef` root element.

```
<ServiceDefinition xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" name="AzureDeploymentProject">
```

In my build I keep the following warning but the package is build with success.

```
ServiceDefinition.csdef: Warning  CloudServices040 : The 'schemaVersion' attribute is unspecified. Please set the attribute to avoid this warning.
```